# Converting a VPython program to an exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze, vpython

I have coded a VPython simulation but I can't compress it into an exe using cx_Freeze. I think it is because of VPython module since cx_Freeze works when I compress other programs that don't use VPython.

Detailed steps:

This is my test simulation program:

```
from vpython import *

### Simulation ###
def run_simulation(r):
    ball = sphere(radius=r)

run_simulation(5)
```

Here is my setup file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='Test',
      version='0.1',
      description='Parse stuff',
      executables=[Executable('Test.py')])
```

I go to the folder which these two are in, hold shift and right click, then press on Windows PowerShell. In the shell I type: python setup.py build

The supposed outcome is a new folder called 'build' (that has the executable) is created in the already existing folder, but instead I get this error on the PowerShell:

KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'

For Simon's answer:
Here is a picture of the error I get when I try to run it, along with my new code in my set up file.

Error: [image: Syntax error on PowerShell]

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = C:\Users\mohamed-tayeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6

setup(name='Test',
    version='0.1',
    description='Parse stuff',
    executables=[Executable('Test.py')])
```

Comment: can you provide more detail steps of this?

Comment: @aircraft Here you go!

Comment: That's not a PowerShell error, so nothing to do with PowerShell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yea I said that this error appeared on the PowerShell, but didn't necessarily mean it had something to do with PowerShell. If you look closely at the first part of the question, I mentioned that I think it was because I am converting a program that uses VPython.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your script requires tkinter (or Vpython might) because it is is missing the "TCL_LIBRARY" and "TK_LIBRARY" (which always go together) which are just a few folders (note that this is not the actual name of the folder  containing the tkinter widgets).

## So what do I do?

Quite simply add the missing folders.

The easiest way you can do this is by either:

- Coping them in the build folder manually
- Using the `environ` function in the `os` module.

Note that the first is only suitable if you are only creating your app in a build folder and not an msi.  If you want to do it correctly then go for the second!

---

I don't know your Python version or path so I'm going to leave making the file paths to you.

---

TCL_LIBRARY is is actually located in `tcl` and is a folder called `tcl8.6` and TK_LIBRARY is named `tk8.6`. Just include those in your build folder.

You need to use `os.environ` to copy it into your build folder:

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = '<path to Python>\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = '<path to Python>\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6'
```

## So what should my script look like now?

Your script should look almost the same except you import `os` and use environ:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = '<path to Python>\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = '<path to Python>\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6'

setup(name='Test',
    version='0.1',
    description='Parse stuff',
    executables=[Executable('Test.py')])
```

There.  The error should disappear now.

Comment: I am a newbie, so just to make sure: I need copy the new code you wrote into my setup folder, with the my own python path, and tada the problem is solved, correct?

Comment: @Momo6aye3 Yes.  Just fill in the paths and you should be good to go!

Comment: @Momo6aye3  If you get the `TK_LIBRARY` error afterwards (you do sometimes) just say so and I'll edit.

Comment: Okay I did that and I got my python path by import the sys model then doing a loop as follows: for p in sys.path: print(p). BUT, I get an error when I try to run it. I attached a picture of the error in the original question. Cheers.

Comment: @Momo6aye3  Fixed.  I presume you are using Python 3.6 32bit?

Comment: @Momo6aye3  See my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162183/discussion-between-simon-and-momo-6aye3).

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I had lost my chat privilege (1 reputation away :/), but here are my answers to your questions/messages. 1. I am a Windows user trying to develop an application for a Mac user. 2. I am not questioning your experience, I am just a curious being :) 3. I am in despair because I dedicated so much time working on this application and I don't want it to go to waste because of the final stage, but thank you supporting me this far (it really means a lot) 4. Background on my application: a projectile motion simulation that the the user inputs data for.